# How does the new Google Sign in Button (Google Identity GSI) determine user locale?

Tags: google-identity

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#locale

> The pre-set locale of the button text. If it's not set, the browser's default locale or the Google session user’s preference is used. Therefore, different users might see different versions of localized buttons, and possibly with different sizes.

I am located in Lithuania (people use Lithuanian (`lt`) language here)

If I open up the page with login button on incognito window than the button is rendered in `lt` locale.

In console `navigator.languages` is `['en']`

Network requests to page and GSI client lib are `accept-language: en`

**How does this happen if I leave the login button locale empty? (default)**

Comment: I am curious to know if you are able to log out of your account from the normal browser or clear cache and cookies to test it (due to the sign in cookies having the profile information or data to "en"). Mainly because the "Google session user preferences" documentation is not clear and I am assuming it has to do with the language being applied to the Google services from https://myaccount.google.com/language

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz no changes at all. My only guess is that they are using IP addresses or more with their own Geolocation services from Google Maps Cloud.

Comment: I wonder if also depends on the OS configuration and how that default language is considered when utilizing the browsers, meaning the browser would use the default language or prioritize it based on the OS language.

Comment: My OS (Mac OS X) preferred language list is `en` and then `lt`. My region is set as `Lithuania`.